# Writing a backspace button for calculator

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a form with a Numbers keyboard and a backspace. The user enters the numbers on a textbox using the numbers provided in the form.  I have a backspace button that I want to program.  I wrote the following:

```
            Private Sub btnBackSpace_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackSpace.Click

    'The procedure works as a backspace for the
    'cash box

    If txtCash.Text < " " Then

        txtCash.Text = Mid(txtCash.Text, 1, Len(txtCash.Text) - 1 + 1)

    Else

        txtCash.Text = Mid(txtCash.Text, 1, Len(txtCash.Text) - 1)

    End If

End Sub
```

The only problem is that it goes from the last character and back, which is fine, but I wanted to also go from the cursor placement.

How can I get that done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Hanlet's solution, but...the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) property of a textbox tells you where the caret sits. From there, you should be able to do the manipulation by hand if so desired.

Comment: +1. I never knew that the "mysterious line" is called a "caret".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    txtCash.Focus()
    SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like

```
    Private Sub btnBackSpace_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackSpace.Click

    'The procedure works as a backspace for the
    'cash box

    If txtCash.Text < " " Then

    Else

        txtCash.Text = Mid(txtCash.Text, 1, Len(txtCash.Text) - 1)

    End If

End Sub
```

think this help :/